# Loop through jQuery elements and sort them as illustrated

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I have an *unknown* number of HTML elements which I have to sort for a type of carousel.

Imagine it is a list of div's like the following:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

Let's say that, for instance, i have 13 div's i need to sort. The following has to been done:

[image]

*Don't get too distracted by the highlighted 8, that's just the active items I'm showing.*

I can't quite figure it out, maybe I've been staring at the thing for too long or tried too many alternatives.

edit:
the illustration is maybe a bit distracting.

the result I want is:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>12</div>
```

Comment: Are you going to sort it in 2 array? Or just want to set the position of each div?

Comment: what do u mean by `jQuery elements` ??

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Just HTML elements.

Comment: first row length is `Math.round(n/2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they were in a container, say `<div id="container">`, just takes the [`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) ones and append them at the end using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), like this:

```
$("#container div:odd").appendTo("#container");
```

[You can try it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/synrB/).  If they're in something else, the concept it the same, take the odd ones, append them to the parent at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine you have two rows `#row1` and `#row2`. Then you can traversing through original collection (which in `#collection` block) this way:

```
var $row1 = $('#row1');
var $row2 = $('#row2');
$('#collection div').each(function(i) {
    if (i % 2) {
        $(this).appendTo($row2)
    } else {
        $(this).appendTo($row1)
    }
});
```

Comment: While this works, it also executes the `#rowX` selectors *each* iteration as well as creating an extra jQuery object each time...best to cache either operation, or avoid the `.each()` loop altogether :)

Comment: You absolutely right. In fact, yours and Piter's answers much better and subtle.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
   $wrapper = $("#wrapper"); 
   $("div:odd", $wrapper).appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed2We/

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 for loops?

```
for(var i=0, j=yourList.length/2; i<j; i+=2){
    doSomething(yourList[i]);
}
for(var i=1, j=yourList.length/2; i<j; i+=2){
    doSomething(yourList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var r1 = new Array();
var r2 = new Array();
$("DIV","#in").each(function(){
    if(parseInt($(this).text()) % 2 == 1 )
        r1.push($(this));
    else
        r2.push($(this));
});
$.fn.append.apply( $("#in"), $.merge(r1,r2));
```

output is:

```
<div>1</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>12</div>
```